# Fluent Validation changing CustomAsync to MustAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, fluentvalidation

Could some one please help me to resolved this? i'm trying to change **CustomAsync to MustAsync**, but i couldn't make things to work. Below is my custom method

```
RuleFor(o => o).MustAsync(o => {
            return  CheckIdNumberAlreadyExist(o)
          });

      private static async Task<ValidationFailure> CheckIdNumberAlreadyExist(SaveProxyCommand command)
      {
          if (command.Id > 0)
              return null;

          using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionSettings.LicensingConnectionString))
          {
              var param = new DynamicParameters();
              param.Add("@idnumber", command.IdNumber);

              var vehicle = await connection.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<dynamic>("new_checkDuplicateProxyIdNumber", param, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

              return vehicle != null
                  ? new ValidationFailure("IdNumber", "Id Number Already Exist")
                  : null;
          }
       }
```

Answer (score 28):

To make it work with the latest version of the FluentValidation, I had to use the codes like below.

```
RuleFor(ws => ws).MustAsync((x, cancellation) => UserHasAccess(x)).WithMessage("User doesn't have access to perform this action");
```

Please notice the lambda expression here `MustAsync((x, cancellation) => UserHasAccess(x))`, without this I was always getting an error as `cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Func<Worksheet, CancellationToken, Task<bool>>`

Below is my custom `UserHasAccess` function.

```
private async Task <bool> UserHasAccess(Worksheet worksheet) {
    var permissionObject = await _dataProviderService.GetItemAsync(worksheet.FileItemId);
    if (permissionObject is null) return false;
    if (EditAccess(permissionObject.Permission)) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you're using a version of FluentValidation prior to version 6, as you're not passing in a Continuation Token, so I've based my answer on version 5.6.2.

Your example code does not compile, for starters, as you're missing a semi-colon in your actual rule. You are also evaluating two different properties on the `SaveProxyCommand` parameter.

I've built a very small POC based on some assumptions:

Given 2 classes:

```
public class SaveProxyCommand {
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class ValidationFailure {
    public string PropertyName { get; }
    public string Message { get; }

    public ValidationFailure(string propertyName, string message){
        Message = message;
        PropertyName = propertyName;
    }
}
```

And a validator:

```
public class SaveProxyCommandValidator : AbstractValidator<SaveProxyCommand>{

    public SaveProxyCommandValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(o => o).MustAsync(CheckIdNumberAlreadyExists)
                       .WithName("Id")
                       .WithState(o => new ValidationFailure(nameof(o.IdNumber), "Id Number Already Exist"));
    }

    private static async Task<bool> CheckIdNumberAlreadyExists(SaveProxyCommand command) {
        if (command.Id > 0)
            return true;

        var existingIdNumbers = new[] {
            1, 2, 3, 4
        };

        // This is a fudge, but you'd make your db call here
        var isNewNumber = !(await Task.FromResult(existingIdNumbers.Contains(command.IdNumber)));

        return isNewNumber;

    }
}
```

I didn't include the call to the database, as that's not part of your problem. There are a couple of things of note here:

1. You're not setting the `.WithName` annotation method, but when you're setting up a validation rule for an object you have to do this, as FluentValidation expects you to specify specific properties to be validated by default, if you pass in an entire object it just doesn't know how to report errors back.
2. Must/MustAsync need to return a `bool`/`Task<bool>` instead of a custom object. To get around this, you can specify a custom state to be returned when failing validation.

You can then get access to this like this:

```
var sut = new SaveProxyCommand { Id = 0, IdNumber = 3 };
var validator = new SaveProxyCommandValidator();
var result = validator.ValidateAsync(sut).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
var ValidationFailures = result.Errors?.Select(s => s.CustomState).Cast<ValidationFailure>();
```

The above does **not** take into account empty collections, it's just an example of how to dig into the object graph to retrieve custom state.

As a suggestion, fluentvalidation works best if you set up individual rules per property, instead of validating the entire object. My take on this would be something like this:

```
public class SaveProxyCommandValidator : AbstractValidator<SaveProxyCommand>{

    public SaveProxyCommandValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(o => o.IdNumber).MustAsync(CheckIdNumberAlreadyExists)
                                .Unless(o => o.Id > 0)
                                .WithState(o => new ValidationFailure(nameof(o.IdNumber), "Id Number Already Exist"));
    }

    private static async Task<bool> CheckIdNumberAlreadyExists(int numberToEvaluate) {
        var existingIdNumbers = new[] {
            1, 2, 3, 4
        };

        // This is a fudge, but you'd make your db call here
        var isNewNumber = !(await Task.FromResult(existingIdNumbers.Contains(numberToEvaluate)));

        return isNewNumber;
    }
}
```

This read more like a narrative, it uses the `.Unless` construct to only run the rule if `Id` is not more than 0, and does not require the evaluation of the entire object.