# Asynchronous fluent validation in Blazor using Mudblazor

Tags: asp.net, validation, blazor, fluentvalidation, mudblazor

**MudBlazor** forms can be validated using Fluent validation in Blazor. I followed the same code found in documentation:

1. Created general *FluentValueValidator* class

```
public FluentValueValidator(Action<IRuleBuilderInitial<T, T>> rule)
{
    rule(RuleFor(x => x));
}
```

2. Created object of that class (ex. *dependencyLinkValidator*)

```
public FluentValueValidator<string> dependencyLinkValidator = new FluentValueValidator<string>(x => x
        .NotEmpty().WithMessage("{PropertyName} cannot be empty.").WithName("Link"));
```

3. Put value of Validator property to *dependencyLinkValidator*

```
Validation="dependencyLinkValidator.Validation"
```

4. The form gets validated when user types a new value in textbox but I also call Form.Validate() when user clicks *submit* button to validate all controls in the form

```
Form.Validate();
```

The example is simple and it works perfectly even with custom validators, the problem is, when I create custom validator that uses async function, the validation doesn't work. Is there any way to call Form.Validate() asynchronously?

Example with custom async validator:

```
 public FluentValueValidator<string> dependencyLinkValidator = new FluentValueValidator<string>(x => x
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("{PropertyName} cannot be empty.")
            .MustAsync(async (x, cancellation) =>
            {
                return await AsyncFunction(x);
            }).WithMessage("Site doesn't exist")
            .WithName("Link"));
```

Comment: Have you asked MudBlazor this question? See this older stackoverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46485741/fluent-validation-changing-customasync-to-mustasync

Comment: I've seen the answer. When I try to use async function, the error i get is _Error in validation func: Cannot wait on monitors on this runtime_. Maybe I'm approaching this problem completely the wrong way, so it would be nice if I could sea a working example. I'll ask MudBlazor as well.

Comment: I assume your running WASM.  Was the error is throw by System.Threading.Monitor?  I
 think the error is because the code would block the thread and cause a deadlock.  WASM only has one thread, there's no threadpool to hand off to.  So I think the answer is you can't do async validation like this in WASM.  Would be interesting to see if it worked in Server?